# Multiple Warehouse with multiple shipping rates

Tags: multistore, magento2.3.1, multishipping

[image]I want to create multiple warehouse and i assign different shipping rate for each warehouse in same website.  Example: I have different product from different place so i create different warehouse so if customer order both i want to assign different shipping rate for each warehouse

Comment: Please describe more about your question

Comment: I have different product from different place so i create different warehouse so if customer order both i want to assign different shipping rate for each warehouse

Answer (score 0):

You can enable shipping carriers, assign shipping rates, price, taxes per source with MSI customer source selector extension.